# How to plot multiple files in single graph using python?

Tags: python

How to plot multiple files in single graph using python? or How can we get graphs from multiple files in a single plot?

I want a code to read multiple files in a single graph plot .

Comment: What kind of files do you have? How is the data structured? You could for example loop over the files, add their content to a single dataframe and then plot this dataframe. But it all depends on what data you have and how you want your graph to be.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example